# How to remove Triplicate Letters in Python

Tags: python

So I'm a little confused as far as putting this small code together. My teacher gave me this info:

> Iterate over the string and remove any triplicated letters (e.g.
>   "byeee mmmy friiiennd" becomes "bye my friennd"). You may assume any
>   immediate following same letters are a triplicate.

I've mostly only seen examples for duplicates, so how do I remove triplicates? My code doesn't return anything when I run it.

```
def removeTriplicateLetters(i):
    result = ''
    for i in result:
        if i not in result:
            result.append(i)
    return result

def main():
    print(removeTriplicateLetters('byeee mmmy friiiennd'))


main()
```

Comment: What about 4 in row? Results in 1 or 2 occurrences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going in to writing the code to resolve the problem.

When you iterate over the string, add that iteration to a new string. 
If the next iteration is the same as the previous iteration then do not add that to the new string.

This will catch both the triple and the double characters in your problem.
Tweaked a previous answer to remove a few lines that were not needed.

```
def remove_n_plicates(input_string, n):
    i=0
    result = ''
    while(True):
        result += input_string[i]
        if input_string[i:i+n] == input_string[i]*n:
            i += n
        else:
            i += 1

        if i >= len(input_string):
            break
    return result


input_string = "byeee mmmy friiiennd"
output_string = remove_n_plicates(input_string, 3)
print(output_string)
# bye my friennd
```

Answer (score 1):

I have generalized the scenario with "n". In your case, you can pass n=3 as below

```
def remove_n_plicates(input_string, n):
    i=0
    final_string = ''
    if not input_string:
        return final_string
    while(True):
        final_string += input_string[i]
        if input_string[i:i+n] == input_string[i]*n:
            i += n
        else:
            i += 1

        if i >= len(input_string):
            break

    return final_string


input_string = "byeee mmmy friiiennd"
output_string = remove_n_plicates(input_string, 3)
print(output_string)
# bye my friennd
```

You can use this for any "n" value now (where n > 0 and n < length of input string)

Answer (score 1):

Your code returns an empty string because that's exactly what you coded:

```
result = ''
for i in result:
    ...
return result
```

Since `result` is an empty string, you don't enter the loop at all.
If you *did* enter the loop you couldn't return anything:

```
for i in result:
    if i not in result:
```

The `if` makes no sense: to get to that statement, `i` *must* be in `result`

Instead, do as @`newbie` showed you.  Iterate through the string, looking at a 3-character slice.  If the slice is equal to 3 copies of the first character, *then* you've identified a triplet.

```
    if input_string[i:i+n] == input_string[i]*n:
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way using `itertools.groupby`:

```
def removeTriplicateLetters(s):
    return ''.join(k*(l//3+l%3) for k,l in ((k,len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(s)))

>>> removeTriplicateLetters('byeee mmmy friiiennd')
'bye my friennd'
```

Answer (score 0):

just modifying @newbie solution and  using stack data structure as solution

```
def remove_n_plicates(input_string, n):
    if input_string =='' or n<1:
        return None

    w = ''
    c = 0
    if input_string!='':
        tmp =[]
        for i in range(len(input_string)):
            if c==n:
                    w+=str(tmp[-1])
                    tmp=[]
                    c =0

            if tmp==[]:
                tmp.append(input_string[i])
                c = 1
            else:

                if input_string[i]==tmp[-1]:
                    tmp.append(input_string[i])
                    c+=1
                elif input_string[i]!=tmp[-1]:
                    w+=str(''.join(tmp))
                    tmp=[input_string[i]]
                    c = 1
        w+=''.join(tmp)                   


        return w


input_string = "byeee mmmy friiiennd nnnn"
output_string = remove_n_plicates(input_string, 3)
print(output_string)
```

output

```
bye my friennd nn
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already got a working solution. But here, I come with another way to achieve your goal.

```
def removeTriplicateLetters(sentence):
    """
        :param sentence: The sentence to transform.
        :param words: The words in the sentence.
        :param new_words: The list of the final words of the new sentence.

    """
    words = sentence.split(" ") # split the sentence into words
    new_words = []
    for word in words:  # loop through words of the sentence
        new_word = []
        for char in word:   # loop through characters in a word
            position = word.index(char)
            if word.count(char) >= 3:
                new_word = [i for i in word if i != char]
                new_word.insert(position, char)
        new_words.append(''.join(new_word))

    return ' '.join(new_words)


def main():
    print(removeTriplicateLetters('byeee mmmy friiiennd'))


main()
```

> **Output:** `bye my friennd`

Answer (score 0):

so this is a bit dirty but it's short and works

```
def removeTriplicateLetters(i):
    result,string = i[:2],i[2:]
    for k in string:
        if result[-1]==k and result[-2]==k:
            result=result[:-1]
        else:
            result+=k
    return result

print(removeTriplicateLetters('byeee mmmy friiiennd'))
bye my friennd
```